# Display nested data using `admin-on-rest`

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I have data in the following format -

```
{
  "categories": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "code": "TESTCODE001",
    "name": "TESTCODE001",
  "subcategories": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "code": "TESTCODE0002",
      "name": "TESTCODE0002",
      "subcategories": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not able to display subcategories. I have tried using `ReferenceArrayField` but I am not able to use it, as categories and subcategories are fetched from the same API. Also tried using custom component to display subcategories, this is also not possible as it shows the edit form when I click on subcategories.

The code I have written-
categories.js

```
export const CategoryList = (props) => (
    <List title="All categories"  {...props} >
        <Datagrid>
             <TextField source="code" />
             <TextField source="name" />
             <TextField source="id" />
             <LinkToRelatedSubcategories/>
             <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
     </List>
);
```

LinkToRelatedSubcategories.js

```
const LinkToRelatedSubcategories = ({ record, translate }) => (
    <FlatButton
        primary
        label='Subcategories'

        containerElement={<Link params={{ testvalue: "hello" }}
            to={{
                pathname: '/category/categoryId',

            }}
        />}
    />
);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is also not possible as it shows the edit form when I click on subcategories.

For the show page, you can use: `/category/categoryId/show`

Maybe you can use [`react-admin`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) instead of `admin-on-rest`. Its the new version, now in release candidate mode. It has https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#arrayfield and https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#arrayinput

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using `/category/categoryId/show`, I am only able to get details of category. How can I get the details of subcategories?

Comment: You probably should remove the subcategories from your categories and add a optional `parentCategoryId` to the categories. This way you can still identify top level categories and just use `ReferenceInput` and `ReferenceField`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot change the API response.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to create custom components for your use case.

Comment: Edited my answer to mention react-admin which should allow this use case